# adding rows to table1 function r

Tags: r, subset, rows

I'm trying to add sub row to my table1.
I want a sub-row for dividing the table to continuous variables, and sub-row for categorial variables.
I'm using the table1 package, and I can't find the right argument for that. I just want to add two rows in the beggining and in the middle of the table.

currently this is my code:

```
table1(~ fincial_difficulties + economy_preocuupied + MSPS + EPDS + STAI + MPAS
       + age + ethnicity + other_kids | t1, data=t1_t2,
       overall=F, extra.col=list('Statistic'=statistic, 'P-value'=pvalue))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider including example data to make your code reproducible. Also, of course you can assign variables to any string you'd like, but using standard spellings ("financial_difficulties" and "economy_preoccupied") might improve legibility.

Comment: What about using the `table.rows()` function to create the two parts of the table? (one part for continuous variables and the other part for categorical variables.)
Please note that I have never used the table1 package, I just took a 15-min look at the PDF documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/table1.pdf) and at the vignette (https://benjaminrich.github.io/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html) and that's the only tip I could suggest based on that reading. Let me know if it works out!